# How to get multiple objects from Parse to save in Local DataStorage in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm getting objects from Parse and display it in my UI. Now I am working on saving the data in Local DataStorage of Parse. I looked at the following Parse example:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "GameScore")
query.fromLocalDatastore()
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZ4YE").continueWithBlock {
(task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject in
if let error = task.error {
    // Something went wrong.
    return task;
}

// task.result will be your game score
return task;
}
```

The above example if for fetching 1 object. I dont know how to do the same for multiple objects. I am fetching the objects through MY following code:

```
let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Events")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (object, error) -> Void in
        if object != nil
        {
            if(object!.count != 0)
            {
                for messageObject in object! {
                    let eventName:String? = (messageObject as! PFObject)["EventName"] as? String
                    let createdBy:String? = (messageObject as! PFObject)["CreatedBy"] as? String
                    let eventDate:String? = (messageObject as! PFObject)["EventDate"] as? String
                    objModalClass.eveName = eventName!
                    objModalClass.crtedBy = createdBy!
                    objModalClass.eveVenue = eventVenue!

                }
            }
        }
     }
```

In my above code, how can I save all the fetched objects in `objModalClass` in Local DataStorage. Kindly explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should look object pinning. As long as you have enabled the local datastore, you can retrieve objects by a pin name, as well as releasing those objects from the local datastore with unpinning. From the docs:

"Asynchronously stores the object and every object it points to in the local datastore, recursively."

For single objects:

```
public func pinInBackgroundWithName(name: String, block:PFBooleanResultBlock?)
```

For many objects:

```
public class func pinAllInBackground(objects: [AnyObject]?, withName name: String, block: PFBooleanResultBlock?)
```

The complementary `unpinWithName(name: String)` is available for both scenarios. Pinning only works with `PFObject`s and its subclasses.

You can also query from a pin name like so

```
var query = PFQuery.queryWithClassname("PFObject_subclass")
query.fromPinWithName("Your_given_pin_name")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    //objects from pin name returned.        
}
```